# Parsing XML values with xml.etree

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

probably a very simple question - but I'm a python/xml newbie and cant seem to find an answer that works for me.

I am trying to parse xml values  and  from an xml reponse as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
xmlstr = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<biwsXML_response type="find">
 <clientdata>
  <message></message>
  <query>jurnamn:Acme Ltd</query>
  <wpquery></wpquery>
  <wpfilter></wpfilter>
 </clientdata> 
 <records total="1">
  <record nr="1">
   <nummer>9990874474</nummer>
   <orgnr>9990874474</orgnr>
   <jurnamn>Acme1 Ltd</jurnamn>
   <ba_postort>T&#228;by</ba_postort>
   <abv_ugrupp></abv_ugrupp>
  </record>
  <record nr="2">
   <nummer>9890874474</nummer>
   <orgnr>9890874474</orgnr>
   <jurnamn>Acme2 Ltd</jurnamn>
   <ba_postort>T&#228;by</ba_postort>
   <abv_ugrupp></abv_ugrupp>
  </record>
 </records>
</biwsXML_response>
"""
biwsXML_response = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
for records in list(biwsXML_response):
    orgnr = records.find('orgnr').text
    jurnamn = records.find('jurnamn').text
    print('orgnr: %s; jurnamn: %s' % (orgnr, jurnamn))
```

When I test I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_xml_tst2.py", line 31, in <module>
    orgnr = records.find('orgnr').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I understand that I am not finding the value 'NoneType' but I don't understand were the error is.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: In `clientdata`.  There is no `orgnr` element (nor is there a `jurnamn`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to go further down in the XML tree. To get to  `orgnr` you have to go first into `records` and then into `record`:

This should help you:

```
for record in biwsXML_response.find('records').findall('record'):
    orgnr = record.find('orgnr').text
    jurnamn = record.find('jurnamn').text
    print('orgnr: %s; jurnamn: %s' % (orgnr, jurnamn))
```

Comment: Thanks for the succinct code and clear solution. Also to the others for a good explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the records will look at the `<clientdata>` and `<records>` elements.

You are then performing a search of the next layer for each of these elements for elements with the tag `orgnr`.  This tag does not exist in `clientdata` at all and is 2 layers deep in `records`.   So it is return `None` for both.

The `.find` method does support XPath expressions, which is what you need to use to search deeper.

```
orgnr = biwsXML_response.find('.//orgnr').text
jurnamn = biwsXML_response.find('.//jurnamn').text
```

Now keep in mind `.find` only return the **first** element that is finds, not all of the matching elements.  For that you need to use either `.findall` or `.iterfind`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that

```
records.find('orgnr').text
```

...well, you can, but it's a run-time error waiting to happen. There is no guarantee that `.find()` returns something useful, so you can't write code that ignores this fact.

In your case, the error occurs when the code is processing the `clientdata` element.

Either

- store `records.find('orgnr')` in a variable and check that it is not `None` before you try to access it any further, or
- use `.findall()` and a loop, so that the loop body is not executed when nothing was found, or
- create a small helper function that gets the text of an element

Apart from that, `.find()` as well as `.findall()` can work with XPath. It might be better to search for specific elements right from the start.

All three suggestions combined below:

```
biwsXML_response = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)

def get_text(context_element, xpath, default=''):
    element = context_element.find(xpath)
    return element.text if element else default

for record in biwsXML_response.findall('./records/record'):
    orgnr = get_text(record, './orgnr', 'N/A')
    jurnamn = get_text(record, './jurnamn', 'N/A')

    print('orgnr: %s; jurnamn: %s' % (orgnr, jurnamn))
```